# how to summarize min and max of two separate columns in one column

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a data of bond market like this:

```
Id   row      Date       BuyPrice    SellPrice
1    1      2017-10-30    94520       0
1    2      2017-10-30    94538       0
1    3      2017-10-30    94609       0
1    4      2017-10-30    94615       0
1    5      2017-10-30    94617       0
1    1      2017-09-20    99100       99059
1    1      2017-09-20    98100       99090
2    1      2010-11-01    99890       100000
2    2      2010-11-01    99899       100000
2    3      2010-11-01    99901       99899
2    4      2010-11-01    99920       99850
2    5      2010-11-01    99933       99848
```

I want to choose the lowest sell price and highest buy price for each id and calculate their subtraction but if any of minimum of sell or price is zero i want to make an exception and drop out that date.

And also give each id an index by date. means for the first day of each give 1 and second day give 2 and so on.

At last data should be like this:

```
Id    Date    highest buy price     lowest sell price       NBBO(highest buy price - lowestSellPrice)Index

1     2017-10-30    94520                  0                       NaN                                 1
1     2017-09-20    99100                  99059                   41                                  2      
2     2017-11-01    99890                  99848                   42                                  1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate `min` and max first and then [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for `NaN`s by condition. Last use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['Id','Date'], sort=False).agg({'BuyPrice':'max','SellPrice':'min'})
df['NBBO'] = np.where(df[['BuyPrice', 'SellPrice']].eq(0).any(1), 
                      np.nan, 
                      df['BuyPrice'] -  df['SellPrice'])
df['index'] =  df.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1

d = {'BuyPrice':'highest buy price','SellPrice':'lowest sell price'}
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns=d)
print (df)

   Id        Date  highest buy price  lowest sell price  NBBO  index
0   1  2017-10-30              94617                  0   NaN      1
1   1  2017-09-20              99100              99059  41.0      2
2   2  2010-11-01              99933              99848  85.0      1
```

Detail:

```
#comapre with 0 eq is same as ==
print (df[['BuyPrice', 'SellPrice']].eq(0))
               BuyPrice  SellPrice
Id Date                           
1  2017-10-30     False       True
   2017-09-20     False      False
2  2010-11-01     False      False

#get at least one True per row by any(1)
print (df[['BuyPrice', 'SellPrice']].eq(0).any(1))
Id  Date      
1   2017-10-30     True
    2017-09-20    False
2   2010-11-01    False
dtype: bool
```